# Font installation question

Tags: fonts

I installed a font. It showed up both in Font Book and Photoshop. But not Illustrator. Why? But yet this says not installed.[image]

Comment: Now it shows up in Illustrator, but doesn't work so now I am more baffled. I had completely quit Illustrator to see if it showed up when I restarted and it did.

Comment: It has gone from saying it isn't installed to saying it is. So, why won't it work?

Comment: Ok, please it isn't just this font but others as well. So what is going on please? I am trying to work on something for my brother and it is slightly aggravating not to have your fonts working properly.

Comment: All I know is that font files in the Fonts folder (in windows) will be available in illustrator immediately, or after a computer restart.

Comment: The font's name shows up in Illustrator, but when you try and use it you get defaulted to Myrid Pro. : (

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like the font file is corrupted somehow. Is it available for free online? You might try downloading a fresh copy, deleting the one from your font folder, putting the new one in and then restarting your computer.  It looks like Edward Gorey writing :)

Comment: Yes, thankfully the font is free. I will try your suggestion and cross my fingers. : )

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested. This time instead of defaulting to Myrid Pro, it picked the font directly above it instead.

Comment: So weird. Did you say it does work in your other programs? Maybe type your text in Word and paste into illustrator?

Comment: Also, what happens when you type in illustrator, select text and scroll down all your fonts to the one you want?

Comment: It shows up in Photoshop, but it doesn't work there either. I am afraid that doesn't work either. I wish that I could message the designer of the font and ask him why it won't work? At this point I am rather frustrated. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Does Font Book have a cache? or something like that ? What if I cleared that? I would still have my fonts right?

Comment: I kind of wish I had paid for it so then I would have someone to message that it isn't working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53908/discussion-between-elizabeth-hart-and-webstarian).

Answer (score 1):

The problem  turned out to be that this font pictured above, "anchors away" only included the characters shown, 26 capital letters and 10 numerals. The lowercase letters were not assigned characters so when used they defaulted to system font.

The solution was to type in caps. This problem was really caused by an improperly formatted font file. Capital fonts that I've used place a capitol when typing a lowercaee letter.